# RestSharp: GET request in hitbtc.com, C#

Tags: c#, api, get, restsharp

I'm trying to get the orderbook of hitbtc via Rest api. How do I get the content in a MessageBox?

```
var client = new RestClient("http://api.hitbtc.com");
var request = new RestRequest("/api/2/orderbook/ETHBTC", Method.GET);
request.AddParameter("nonce", GetNonce().ToString());
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
var response = client.Execute(request);

MessageBox.Show(response.Content);
```

MessageBox shows:

[image]

Comment: Complete your code by making it a minimal working example.

Comment: What is the HTTP code of the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrect request URL.

Please review documentation [page](https://api.hitbtc.com/).

As you can see for method **Orderbook** is used `GET /api/2/public/orderbook/{symbol}` URL.

Just change your code as in the next sample:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.hitbtc.com");
var request = new RestRequest("api/2/public/orderbook/ETHBTC", Method.GET);
request.AddParameter("limit", "100");
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
var response = client.Execute(request);
MessageBox.Show(response.Content);
```

You can use parameter `limit = 0` to view full orderbook list.

Also you can test API actions [here](https://api.hitbtc.com/api/2/explore/) (sometimes it helps very well).

**EDIT:**

Always check returned response code.

If you have error in response you need to processed the error.

Example:

```
var response = client.Execute(request);
if (!response.IsSuccessful)
{
    // Process error here...
    var message = $"REQUEST ERROR (Status Code: {response.StatusCode}; Content: {response.Content})";
    throw new Exception(message);
}
```

Comment: May you help me with the POST method?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48359629/hitbtc-post-request-c-sharp

Comment: @kemmel please review my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48359629/hitbtc-api-post-request-c-sharp/48371534#48371534