# HitBTC api POST request, C#

Tags: c#, .net, post, webrequest

I know how to do a GET request, but POST does not work:

```
public string Order()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://api.hitbtc.com");
        var request = new RestRequest("/api/2/order", Method.POST);
        request.AddQueryParameter("nonce", GetNonce().ToString());
        request.AddQueryParameter("apikey", HapiKey);

       // request.AddParameter("clientOrderId", "");
        request.AddParameter("symbol", "BCNUSD");
        request.AddParameter("side", "sell");
        request.AddParameter("quantity", "10");
        request.AddParameter("type", "market");

        var body = string.Join("&", request.Parameters.Where(x => x.Type == ParameterType.GetOrPost));

        string sign = CalculateSignature(client.BuildUri(request).PathAndQuery + body, HapiSecret);
        request.AddHeader("X-Signature", sign);

        var response = client.Execute(request);
        return response.Content;
    }
    private static long GetNonce()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.Ticks * 10;
    }

    public static string CalculateSignature(string text, string secretKey)
    {
        using (var hmacsha512 = new HMACSHA512(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey)))
        {
            hmacsha512.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
            return string.Concat(hmacsha512.Hash.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")).ToArray());
        }
    }
```

Error: code: 1001, "Authorization required".

Where is my failure?  Is "apikey" and "X-Signature" not correct for v2 anymore?

Thank you very much for helping me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please review authentication [documentation](https://api.hitbtc.com/#authentication).

You need to use Basic authentication using public and private key.

Example for RestSharp:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.hitbtc.com")
{
    Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(<PublicKey>, <SecretKey>)
};
```

For creating API keys you need to visit Setting page.

Also for your API action you need to set "Place/cancel orders" permission to `true`.

Details on the screenshot:
[image]

Also here is full code which works for me well:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.hitbtc.com")
{
    Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(PublicKey, SecretKey)
};

var request = new RestRequest("/api/2/order", Method.POST)
{
    RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
};

request.AddParameter("symbol", "BCNUSD");
request.AddParameter("side", "sell");
request.AddParameter("quantity", "10");
request.AddParameter("type", "market");
request.AddParameter("timeInForce", "IOC");

var response = client.Execute(request);
if (!response.IsSuccessful)
{
    var message = $"REQUEST ERROR (Status Code: {response.StatusCode}; Content: {response.Content})";
    throw new Exception(message);
}
```

Comment: Why does HitBtc feel the need for the private key to be passed? Pretty much all the other exchanges use a hash of the private key, eliminating the need to pass it over the wire. I understand it's https connection but still...

Comment: It's shocking how badly things are encrypted in crypto.

Comment: The basic authentication seems to not work anymore. There is a second type of authorization they allow you to use though